# Search string into dbms_xplan.display_awr output

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c

I want to search into the result of this query.

```
Select 
cursor(select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_awr(sql_id,
plan_hash_value,null,'all +outline +peeked_binds'))) "PLAN" 
from gv$sql 
where sql_id='3cu6fsfskqgst'
```

This query give us the plan of a select execution

```
{<PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT=SQL_ID 3cu6fsfskqgst>,
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT=-------------------->,<PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT = 
Select count(*) ................................................ 
Degree of Parallelism is 4 because of hint>,<PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT=   - 
SQL patch "patch_forzar_paralelo4_tcarga" used for this statement>, 
< PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT= >,}
```

But I only want to show this piece of the string

```
SQL patch "patch_forzar_paralelo4_tcarga"
```

The "string" is not always the same.

Can I cut this piece of the string and show it into the screen?. I want to use only sql execution (not plSql).

Thanks

Comment: What parts of the string are constant? Would `SQL patch "` till the next double quote sufficient to identify it?

Comment: From "SQL patch"  some text  and finished by ">"